# How do I apply touches to images, using Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I need code this game for iOS, using Swift; but I don't know how to apply touches to images, using Swift. My attempts thus far have failed; `touch!.view != image`.

[image]

```
override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    let touchesSet = touches as NSSet
    let touch = touchesSet.anyObject() as? UITouch
    let location = touch?.location(in: self.view)
    if touch!.view == bee1 {
        bee1?.center = location!
    } else if touch!.view == bee2 {
        bee2?.center = location!
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you asking how to detect when a user has touched within the opaque portion of an image? The more detail you can offer about what you're trying to do, the better answers you can get. "Help me this game" doesn't give us a lot to go on.

Comment: I can't move this images

Answer (score 0):

I am still new to Sprite Kit but I think you can solve your problem with this function. It's easy and simple.

I would split your unfilled image in 3. unfilled_left_wing, unfilled_right_wing, unfilled_head.

Then I would move the image to the desired position. If the filled image intersects with the unfilled one, check how far it's from it's center, if it's smaller than 30 px apply it.

```
func touchDown(atPoint pos: CGPoint, atTime t: TimeInterval) {
        // have to start inside the left_wing
        guard left_wing.contains(pos) else {
            return
        }
    }

func touchMoved(atPoint pos: CGPoint, atTime t: TimeInterval) {
    // move wing to cursor position
    left_wing.position = pos
}

func touchUp(atPoint pos : CGPoint, atTime t: TimeInterval) {
     left_wing.position = pos

     // check if it intersects with unfilled image
     if (left_wing.frame.intersects(unfilled_left_wing.frame)
      {
          //check if it's close to center
          if (fabs(left_wing.frame.origin.x - unfilled_left_wing.origin.x) < 30 && fabs(left_wing.frame.origin.y - unfilled_left_wing.origin.y) < 30)
         {
             left_wing.position = unfilled_left_wing.position
         }

      }

    }


// overridden touch method to call our touch method for each touch
override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for t in touches { touchMoved(atPoint: t.location(in: self), atTime: t.timestamp) }
}
override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for t in touches { touchUp(atPoint: t.location(in: self), atTime: t.timestamp) }
}
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for t in touches { touchDown(atPoint: t.location(in: self), atTime: t.timestamp) }
}
```

Based on this method, you can further optimise your code and save the images on NSArray for a dynamic check.